# Select and Organize DIV Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, select

I have the below layout for a bunch of inputs on a page and I would like to arrange them based on whether or not a value is present within an input field.

If the "parent" container has a `<tr class="Off">` then the entire thing should be moved into the `<div class="lowerParent">` and if it contains `<tr class="On">` then move it to the `<div class="upperParent">`.

The purpose behind this is that I have a page with potentially 50+ inputs, not all of which are going to be used, and I would like to move those which have values toward the top, so the user doesn't have to scroll down a huge page of input fields that are mostly not used.

```
<div class='upperParent'></div>
<div class='lowerParent'></div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="collapsed">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="headers">
                    <input type="text" name="ind1" value="0"><input type="text" name="ind2" value="1">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="On">
                <td class="subHeaders">Sub Header 1</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="datafieldtag_value[33]" value="1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="On">
                <td class="subHeaders">Sub Header 2</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="datafieldtag_value[34]" value="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="On">
                <td class="subHeaders">Sub Header 3</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="datafieldtag_value[35]" value="3"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="collapsed">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="headers">
                    <input type="text" name="ind1" value="0"><input type="text" name="ind2" value="1">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="Off">
                <td class="subHeaders">Sub Header 1</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="datafieldtag_value[36]" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="Off">
                <td class="subHeaders">Sub Header 2</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="datafieldtag_value[37]" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="Off">
                <td class="subHeaders">Sub Header 3</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="datafieldtag_value[38]" value=""></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the parent has a ??? then it should be moved into the ??? and if it contains ??? then move it to the ???. Please fill in the gaps ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.parent').each(function(){
    if($('tr.Off', this).length > 0){
        $(this).appendTo('.upperParent');
    }else if($('tr.On', this).length > 0){
        $(this).appendTo('.lowerParent');
    }
});
```

For each div, check if there exists a `tr.Off`, if so put it in the upperParent, else put it in lowerParent.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6H6kp/1/

Comment: This seems to be doing exactly what I want when testing on jsfiddle, but it's freezing in my implementation. Maybe because I have too many .parent containers to check through? I am not sure what else would cause it not to work for me.

Comment: if you have 50+, it might be a little slow, but it wouldn't freeze. If you are getting any errors in your js console, feel free to post them here. Or create a fiddle that more accurately replicates your environment.

Comment: I probably have 300+ inputs, but I have this working now. Perhaps there is a more efficient method for weighting these items, if anyone has a suggestion, I would greatly appreciate it. Nevertheless, your solution is perfect and does exactly what I asked for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have

```
<div class='upperParent'><table></table></div>
<div class='lowerParent'><table></table></div>
```

You can do

```
$('.upperParent table').append( $("tr.On").detach() );
$('.lowerParent table').append( $("tr.Off").detach() );
```

Misread the question.

Comment: He wants to move the entire `.parent` div, not just the rows... at least I think that's what he meant by "then the entire thing should be moved"

Comment: That is correct, I would like to move the entire .parent div and everything inside of it.